# Determine logaritmic function based on samples of unique visitors

Tags: calculus

I need to estimate the unique visitors for any given number of days. I have the unique visitors per day, day, week and month.

```
 1 day :  20000 visitors
 7 days:  85000 visitors
30 days: 200000 visitors
```

How can I determine a logaritmic function that has these 3 points?

Comment: A general technique is to take the log of the dependent variable, plot them, and pray it comes out linear. If not, use normal techniques to make a quadratic or cubic.   BTW.  I see 3 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should expect the unique visitors to grow quickly the first days.

The visitors coming back after a long period is relatively small, but there will always be a group of new visitors. So in the long run the numbers should be almost linear.

This would suggest a logarithmic function like:
$$
a*log(x+1) + bx
$$
[image: Log plot]

Determining `a` and `b` this function based on samples is fairly hard. However the function can be approached for $x > 1$ with:
$$
\sqrt{ax^2+bx}
$$
[image: Sqrt]

`a` and `b` can be calculated using [Quadatic regression](http://www.had2know.com/academics/quadratic-regression-calculator.html).

With 3 samples and $y=0$ on $x=0$ the function would not exactly pass through all 3 points, but it'd be a best fit. Taken that we don't really care about $x<1$, the best is to introduce `c` having the error biggest on $t=0$ and becoming less relevant for a bigger `x`.

$$
\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}
$$

We calculate `a`, `b` and `c` using the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).

$$
a = (x3*(y2-y1) + x2*(y1-y3) + x1*(y3-y2)) / ((x1-x2) * (x1-x3) * (x2-x3))
$$
$$
b = (x3^2(y1-y2) + x1^2(y2-y3) + x2^2*(y3-y1) )/ ((x1-x2) * (x1-x3) * (x2-x3))
$$
$$
c = (x3*(x2*(x2-x3)*y1 + x1*(x3-x1)*y2) + x1*(x1-x2)*x2*y3) / ((x1-x2) * (x1-x3) * (x2-x3))
$$

*This answer is courtesy of Nico Schoonderwoerd aka [@klup](http://www.twitter.com/klup)*

Comment: I just scatter plotted the data in Excel, right clicked the graph and added a trendline.  It will give you various shapes and print the equation on the graph.  If you need the numbers in a subsequent calculation, LINEST or something else is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Logarithmic functions have trouble with $0$, so you will have to exclude that one.  I just fed the other three to Excel and found visitors$=51856 \ln t+ 9240$ but it is not a very good fit.  Much better is an power law:  visitors$=20748t^{0.6806}$

Comment: Cool, but I need to be able to keep calculating that formula when the numbers change.